# Using Tasks to perform delayed "timer-style" operations

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have an event in my application which mutates an object's state and refers that state to be reset 10 seconds later. But if that event is fired again within that those 10 seconds, the event does not change the state but simply resets the timer to zero.

To make it concise and easier to understand, **Here is what my code does**

1. I have an event that schedules tasks to be run 10 seconds later
2. If one task of a certain type is scheduled, and another request for the same comes in, the "execution time" for the existing future task is adjusted.

Currently I am doing it using a 'ConcurrentQueue' being manipulated in a Thread

```
public class ToDo
{
 public DateTime Expires { get; set; }
 public Action StuffToDo { get; set; }
}
```

Then my thread

```
public void MyWorkerThread(object parameters)
{
 while (!<check if cancellation requested>)
 {
   ToDo stuff;
   if (myConcurrentQueue.TryDequeue(out stuff))
   {
     if (DateTime.Now > stuff.Expires)
      {
        Task.StuffToDo.Invoke();
      }
     else 
      {
       // queue it back if it is not time to execute it
       //
        myConcurrentQueue.Enqueue(stuff);
      }
   }
 }
}
```

Here is my event handler that queues tasks

```
private ConcurrentDictionary<ToDo> _todoDictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<ToDo>();
private ConcurrentQueue<ToDo> myConcurrentQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<ToDo>();
public void MyEventFired(MyEventArgs e)
{
 ToDo todo = null;

 if (_todoDictionary.ContainsKey(e.TaskType)) 
 {
   _todoDictionary.TryRemove(out todo);
   if (DateTime.Now >= task.Expires) 
   {
     todo = new ToDo();
     todo.StuffToDo = new Action(() => { /* stuff here */ });
   }   
 } 
 else
 {
   todo = new ToDo();
   todo.StuffToDo = new Action(() => { /* stuff here */ });
 }

 todo.Expires = DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10.0);

 _todoDictionary.Add(e.TaskType, todo);
 myConcurrentQueue.Enqueue(todo);
}
```

Someone hinted to me that I could do all the above using TPL and I don't need a worker thread, I could just use 'Task.Delay'. I am still contemplating on how I will approach it. Any ideas will be appreciated.

**Here is what I want to do**
I am looking to rewrite the worker thread in terms of Task.Run and/or Task.Delay().ContinueWith sequences.

Comment: Post what you want to do, not how you tried to do it. Reactive Extensions already have timers, windows etc. TPL Dataflow already has a queue of messages that get processed by a delegate, which *could* contain a delay. Or you could just write `for(;;){...; await someMethod(someData); await Task.Delay(10000);}`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I want to rewrite the code with the use of TPL. Apologize if my question wasn't obvious enough. I will edit.

Comment: but *what* are you trying to achieve? Process just one message every 10 seconds? Delay 10 seconds between messages? Process all messages received in a 10 second window at a time? Process only *one* message inside a 10 second window?

Comment: For example, Rx's [Throttle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229298(v=vs.103).aspx) can discard incoming events and only process one of them in a 10 second window. The actual syntax is much easier than the docs

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I double-down on my apology. I am apparently a terrible question writer. I edited my question and added what my code does. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Can Throttle reset it's timer? or it will time-out anyway at a given time? and can we throttle based on data separately?

Answer (score 1):

Your current `MyWorkerThread` code is a busy spinning loop. It drive on CPU core to 100%. You should hear your CPU fan spin up because of this.

Here's how I'd implement a resettable delay:

```
volatile int targetTicks = Environment.TickCount + (10 * 1000);

async Task WaitUntilTargetReachedAsync() {
 while (true) {
  var currentTicks = Environment.TickCount; //stabilize value
  var targetTicksLocal = targetTicks; //volatile read, stabilize value
  if (currentTicks >= targetTicksLocal) break; //Target reached.
  await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(targetTicksLocal - currentTicks));
 }
}
```

`WaitUntilTimeoutAsync()` will complete exactly when `targetTicks` is reached. You can add time to `targetTicks` at any time and `WaitUntilTimeoutAsync()` will adjust. This way you can reset the timer to now plus 10 seconds:

```
targetTicks = Environment.TickCount + (10 * 1000);
```

Now that you have a task that completes exactly when you need it you can base your action on that:

```
targetTicks = Environment.TickCount + (10 * 1000); //Initial timer configuration.
await WaitUntilTimeoutAsync();
InvokeMyAction();
```

Comment: No, I left that out. You can use a lock for that. You can mark it `volatile` as well and that's enough. But that's harder to understand and conclude that it's correct.